# Understanding projections in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

I am following a course in functional analysis and in the introductory chapter on Hilbert spaces, orthogonal projections where introduced like this.

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of $H$, then $H$ has an orthogonal decomposition $H = Y \oplus Y^\perp$, where $Y^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of $Y$. This means that for all $h \in H$, there exist unique $h_1 \in Y, h_2 \in Y^\perp$ such that $h = h_1 + h_2$. We call the mapping $\pi_Y: H \rightarrow Y$ defined by $\pi_Y(h) = h_1$ the *orthogonal projection* onto the subspace $Y$.

This I understand perfectly well. However, we also study projections onto sets, rather than closed subspaces. Say the projection $P$ which projects onto some set $B \subset H$. How should I interpret the action of $P$ on some element $h$ of the Hilbert space? The book does not pay attention to this.

Comment: What is the definition of a projection onto a set?

Comment: However you define projection, it must satisfy the condition $p = p^2$. If continuity of the projection is present, this implies that $p$ has closed image. So projecting on other things than closed subspaces does not make sense at all...

Comment: As an example, we encounter such projections in the theory of projection valued measures. A projection valued measure is a mapping that maps a measurable set (in the sigma algebra of some measurable space) to a projection (projection on that set).

Comment: Projections are defined to be mappings that are idempotent. So $P$ is a projection if $P^2 = P$.

Comment: @PROB123 This is something else entirely than the thing you talk about in your question...

Comment: Could you explain how the projections of projection valued measures are different from orthogonal projections (or any other)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a more general result, which says that if $B$ is a closed convex set and $h\in H$, then there exists a unique $b\in B$ such that $\|h-b\|=\operatorname{dist}(h,B)$. This allows you to define $Ph=b$. This $P$ is an idempotent, and sometimes called the projection onto $B$.

When $B$ is a closed subspace, this gives you the projection onto $B$ in the sense you described.